# How to check the number of partitions that a table is distributed in a DolphinDB database?

Tags: partition, dolphindb

How can I know over how many partitions in a DolphinDB database that a table is distributed? For example, if I created a database with 100 partitions and a table in the database only has data in 4 partitions, how do I get the number of 4?

Answer (score 0):

this will do:

```
sqlDS(<select * from t>).size()
```